# loading and inserting millions record in html file from php and mysql how

Tags: php, mysql

i have html file of size upto 1GB. and i want to upload the content of this html file in database. the file(html) contain the `<table><tr><td></td></tr></table>` tags. this work is done if a file size is approximate 5MB or 6MB, but the large file size give me error of OUT OF MEMORY( xxxxx bytes) trying to allocate(xxxxxxx bytes)..

How can i upload large file size data in database..

i use DOMDocument -> LoadHTMLfile function.... and getElementByTagName("tr")

Comment: can you not simply split that 1GB file in several smaller ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is triggered when PHP runs out of memory while trying to allocated memory for an array, variable, etc.  The max amount of memory is specified in php.ini with directive

```
memory_limit = 128M
```

(or similar).  Try increasing the value and see if it helps.  However, if you're exceeding a very large memory allocation (say, 256 MB or over), then there's definitely a flaw in your design, as you should not keep that much data in memory at one time.

If you're processing a file, you should read the file in chunks, insert your data into the database and read further chunk.  For HTML processing SAX parser could be a good idea, [something like this](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2140-PHP-Parse-HTML-documents-using-regular-expressions.html) maybe.

Answer (score 0):

use XMLReader

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php

it doesn't read the entire document into memory at once.